# What API method can be used to get all latests LinkedIn posts?

Tags: linkedin-api

Does [linkedin-api](/questions/tagged/linkedin-api) provide an endpoint to get the latest public posts/ and comments?

Example, GitHub provides https://api.github.com/events API endpoint to get the latest public events (issues, pull requests, etc.)

Comment: for a companyPage? For an User?

Comment: Across LinkedIn.